# About Bootstrap Driver for PIM module

Tags: circuit-design, bootstrap, motordriver

I'm currently designing a bootstrap circuit for a [PIM](https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/352695_5752691.pdf) module drive. The gate driver IC is an [IR2136S](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR213-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c8a02116a5). This PIM module will drive a motor around 400 V, 10 A @ 5 kHz switching frequency and 3 µs deadtime.

It is my first application with a bootstrap circuit. I normally use IPM modules, but this time I also need a rectifier section. I’m not sure the IR2136S can drive this PIM. Can you guide me?

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure about the gate drive capabilities of the driver. The problem with integrated power modules is that they do not lend themselves ideally to simulation.

Comment: @Andyaka You are right. Unfortunately i couldnt find example or eval circuit with these components. What is your suggestion ?

Comment: 4 kW delivery at an efficiency of maybe 90% is a lot of power to dissipate is my first thought so, I would want to simulate the circuit to see whether the heat dissipation is right. If it is you have some questions to ask yourself about choice of the IGBT module. Begin there. If all looks OK (I have my doubts) stick to individual (but more modern) IGBT drivers to give you the information in their data sheets. I probably wouldn't bootstrap either but use an isolated supply on each of the 6 power devices and opto-couple the drive signal.

Comment: You have the input capacitance of the IGBT and the drive current of the driver. Will it be fast enough according to your specifications?

Comment: You're asking "Is my bootstrap circuit good". Where do you show that bootstrap circuit? Please edit the question and add a schematic.

Comment: @winny It is the problem. I dont know the right calculation ways and most of calculations on the internet which published by many different bootstrap ic manufacturers , have a lot of equations and lots of detailed information about igbts or mosfets. Most of those values are not declareted by PIM manufacturers so im not able to trust any of those calculations.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes you are right first i decided to draw a circuit then i changed my mind because i coulnd draw anything. I will change the title. Thanks

Comment: I see. The datasheet was not good in this regard, but if you assume best case scenario with 200 mA high drive and 350 mA low drive into 39 nC, is it fast enough?

Comment: @winny You are right. I have the same doubts about switching speed. As i said before , i have no experiance bootstrap topologies. It seems that current ratings are very low for such a PIM yes but i wasnt sure so for best result, i decided to ask here. I had started search on IR2136s  because of i had many of those in my inventory so i thought maybe i can use them. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Once bootstrapped, it's like any other gate driver as long as the duty cycle is reasonable. Do you need to go to 0 or 100 % duty cycle in your design or are you concerned about the start up sequence where you are bootstrapping your bootstrap circuit? Or normal operation?

Comment: @winny  The dutycycle will change around 0-98%. Yes i just also looking for startup secuence that bootstrap topology needs.  I discovered a new gate driver ic which there is a clear explanation about startup sequence at its datasheet ( IR2114ss ) . It has reletively higher drain ans source current rather than previous gate driver ic.  I will read more about that and will determine operation mode. May i ask , what do you think about new gate driver ic ? What do you mean "normal operation" ?

Comment: 0 and 98 % will require special attention. Not saying it’s impossible with regular bootstrap, but you may need to have special conditions in your code to come out of 0 %. Have you considered a non-bootstrapped approach? It would happily allow you to run 0-100 % without restrictions.

Comment: @winny  After a quick search , I choosed bootstrap because of reducing design cost of isolated power supply and complexity . I actually not familiar with gate drive topologies thanks to IPM devices which includes gate drive circuit. But I m fully open for new ideas. What is your advice for gate drive ?

Comment: Considering the cost of your sixpack+twelve pulse bridge, gate drive transformer won't be much.

Comment: @winny I hope so. Can you guide me a proper document please. And if you have an example circuit diagram that you have done at past, it would be great if you can post it as an example.

Comment: Start here: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2254418.pdf and https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slua618a/slua618a.pdf. Any isolated +15 V supply at say 5 mA would do the job as long as the transformer capacitance is on the low side. You have slow IGBTs and low switching frequency, so this shouldn't be a problem to you.

Comment: @winny  do you think 5mA of 15V power supply for each gate drive will enough for sixpack igbt's. ? Is not that a quite a bit small for this ?

Comment: You probably need a few A for a few us, then hundred us of nothing = mA of average current. Simulate it or crunch the numbers. 39 nC @ 15 V @ 2xfsw = P.

Comment: @winny Hi. I had some research until yesterday and found some solution.  I had focused on optocoupled based gate driver circuit which is like ACPL336j . And for power supply i found B2415LS-1WR3 which is quite cheap one. I will add datasheet of each device and i hope you to check them and confirm the solution is ok or not.

Comment: @winny Also if i B2415LS-1WR3 isolated power supply is good i should use 5 of them i think. 3 for high side and 1 for low side and 1 for brake chopper right ? I also found a good eval board manual this. Another alternative solution I was also searched for is hybrid ic which for isolated dc dc converter but no luck. 

https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/B2415LS-1WR3.html
https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4391EN
EVAL: https://www.fujielectric.com/products/semiconductor/model/power_modules/igbt/evaluation/box/doc/pdf/MT6M14257_E.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152122/discussion-between-winny-and-qwertyqwq).